# Windows 2016 IIS TLS 1.3 support

Tags: windows, security, ssl

We're building an ASP.NET MVC app for deployment on Windows Server 2016 and IIS. We ran the server through the [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) scan and it gave this as one of the results:

> This server is vulnerable to the Return Of Bleichenbacher's Oracle Threat (ROBOT) vulnerability. Grade will be set to F from March 2018.

A remedy suggested on their "More info" page was to move to TLS 1.3. However, as this post's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155354/tls-1-3-iis-10-0-support#comment77281074_45155354) indicates, 1.3 is in draft mode as of summer 2017.

Has TLS 1.3 become available for Windows servers? If not, is there a timeline for its release?

Comment: As mentioned in chat my WS2016 box is not vulnerable to this according to an SSLLabs scan.

Comment: @RudiVisser, thanks. Wondering why we get it listed on our scan.

Comment: @RudiVisser, thanks for this: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-tls13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has TLS 1.3 become available for Windows servers? If not, is there a timeline for its release?

TLS 1.3 is still in Draft and there is no expected release date as of now. It could be this year, it could be next-year.

You might want to look into the Security Stack Exchange for tips on remediation (if necessary) for the indicated vulnerability. I would suggest verifying that the system *is actually vulnerable* before going down the remediation steps.